# Unable to Locate the Text in Xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am writing relational xpath i need this code to fetch "Tax" Location

```
<td id="td26" style="width: 16%">
<div class="bglabel" style="width: 150px; clear: both">
Tax 
<div style="float: right;">
</div>
</td>
```

Xpath Code which i have written

```
td[div[text()='Tax ']] - Not Working
td[div[contains(text(),'Tax')]] - Not Working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer changes OP's intended logic.

What OP's trying to do is to find `div` with text "Tax" inside a `td`, therefore OP's own answer is on the right track, the accepted answer isn't.

`//div[contains(text(),'Tax')]` locates it anywhere in DOM, which is likely to cause trouble.

What OP wants is (using `.` to specify current node):

```
//td[./div[contains(text(),'Tax')]]
```

Imagine there is another `div` also contains text "Tax", `//div[contains(text(),'Tax')]` will find the one OP doesn't want.

```html
<div>Tax table</div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td26" style="width: 16%">
      <div class="bglabel" style="width: 150px; clear: both">Tax <div style="float: right;"></div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

@Santhosh.S: Hope this makes sense to you.